# JBoss CLI connects to the wrong port, even though its specified right

Tags: jboss, command-line-interface, wildfly

I am using JBoss version 7.0.9.

When I start it, it writes this line to the console:

```
<date> <loginfo> WFLYSRV0051: <german description that says, that this is the admin console>: http://127.0.0.1:9995
```

Now I want to connect to the CLI with the following command:

```
jboss-cli.bat -c --controller:127.0.0.1:9995
```

OR

```
jboss-cli.bat -c --controller:localhost:9995
```

Both throw the following

```
Failed to connect to the controller: The controller is not available at localhost:9990: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Konnte keine Verbindung mit http-remoting://localhost:9990 herstellen. Die Verbindung ist fehlgeschlagen: WFLYPRT0053: Konnte keine Verbindung mit http-remoting://localhost:9990 herstellen. Die Verbindung ist fehlgeschlagen: Connection refused: no further information
```

As you can see it says, that it tries to connect to `localhost:9990`, even though I said that the controller is `localhost:9995`.

Why is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be an equals (`=`) sign instead of a colon (`:`) to assign a command-line argument:

```
 jboss-cli.bat --connect --controller=localhost:9995
 #                                    ^
 #                                    Here
```